# identify $u(n)$ with $u(n)^*$

Tags: lie-algebras, duality-theorems

I'm checking right now a book, in which the authors say, that they identify the dual spaces of the lie algeba $u(n) = \{A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} | \overline{A} = -A^T \}$ again with $u(n)$ by using the Killingform.

But this shoudn't be possible? As $u(n)$ is not semisimple, the Killingform is degenerate, therefore it shouldn't be even an isomorphism...

So is there some other possibility to identify the dual of $u(n)$ with $u(n)$?

Comment: See also [this MSE questioon](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805594/is-there-a-definition-of-a-dual-lie-algebra).

Comment: So what I understood, is that there exists a possibility to identify $u(n)^*$ with $u(n)$, as we are in the finite dimensional case. If I take a basis $X_i$ of $u(n)$ and denote by $c_{ij}^k$ the structure constants, namely $ \[X_i, X_j\] = c_{ij}^k X_k$, then I get a lie-algebra structure on $u(n)^*$ by $[X^*_i, X^*_j]=-c_{ij}^k X_k^*$ with $X_i^*$ the dual of $X_i$. But in my book, they identifiy $u(n)^*$ with $u(n)$ using the Killingform and (after dividing by i) they identify it with $ n \times n $ hermitian matrices. Is that still possible, although the Killingform is degenerate?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer. But the authors of the book meant by $i$ the imaginary unit. Or did you mean first to identify $mathfrak{su}(n)^*$ with $mathfrak{su}(n)$  by the Killingform and then to expand this to $u(n)$ ?

Comment: Can we not identify $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ with its dual via the inner product $(A,B)=trace(A^*B)$ ? The Killing form is indeed degenerate.

Comment: Somehow, I thought the inner product is the same as the killing form, as it is in some special cases expect for some constants... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: **Not a duplicate**; the linked question is about a Lie algebra structure on the dual, which is not being proposed here. @glS