# Lie bracket on the dual of a lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak g$ its Lie algebra.

The Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{g}$ is defined using adjoint representation.
For every $g \in G$ conjugation by $g$, $c_g: G \to G$ is a diffeomorphism that fixes identity. We define adjoint representation $\operatorname{Ad}: G \to \operatorname{Aut} \mathfrak g$ by differentiating $c_g$ at identity, $\operatorname{Ad}(g) = c_{g*}$.

We differentiate once more at identity to obtain $\operatorname{ad}: \mathfrak g \to \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak g)$, $\operatorname{ad} = \operatorname{Ad}_{*}$.
Then, Lie bracket on $\mathfrak g$ is defined as $[X, Y] = \operatorname{ad}(X)(Y)$.

I would like to know if there is a way to define a lie bracket on the dual $\mathfrak{g}^*$ ?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional then $\mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$  as vector spaces. So we can define the same Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ on the underlying vector space. The problem is your "dual Lie algebra" in the title. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805594/is-there-a-definition-of-a-dual-lie-algebra), why.

Comment: The Lie bracket on the Lie algebra can be defined directly by taking Lie bracket as smooth vector fields (the Lie algebra is identified as the set of left-invariant vector fields)