# Dual of short exact sequence of Lie algebras exact?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, exact-sequence, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Let $\varphi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{q}$ be a morphism of finite-dimensional Lie algebras over a field $K$. Define $\varphi^\vee:\mathfrak{q}^\vee\to\mathfrak{g}^\vee$, $l\mapsto l\circ\varphi$, where $\mathfrak{g}^\vee$ is the $K$-vector space of all Lie algebra morphisms from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $K$. Let $0\to\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathfrak{g}\xrightarrow{\varphi}\mathfrak{q}\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of Lie algebras.

**Question: Is the "dual" sequence of vector spaces $0\to\mathfrak{q}^\vee\xrightarrow{\varphi^\vee}\mathfrak{g}^\vee\xrightarrow{\iota^\vee}\mathfrak{h}^\vee\to 0$ also exact?**

My thoughts: I was able to prove that $\varphi^\vee$ is injective and that $\text{im}(\varphi^\vee)\subset\text{ker}(\iota^\vee)$. To prove the other inclusion, I tried proving that one can identify $\text{ker}(\iota^\vee)$ with a subspace of $\text{im}(\iota)^\vee$ and that one can identify $\text{ker}(\varphi)^\vee$ with a subspace of $\text{im}(\varphi^\vee)$. I was able to prove the former of these identifications.

I have trouble showing the rest, i.e. showing that $\iota^\vee$ is surjective and that $\text{ker}(\iota^\vee)\subset\text{im}(\varphi^\vee)$ (or that there exists an injective linear map $\text{ker}(\varphi)^\vee\hookrightarrow\text{im}(\varphi^\vee)$). For surjectivity, I know that $\iota$ has a linear retraction but of course it need not respect the brackets. The vector space dual version of this statement uses the fact that every vector subspace has a complement but of course we cannot assume that every Lie subalgebra has a complementary Lie algebra. Any ideas?

Edit: I have been able to prove everything except the surjectivity of $\iota^\vee$.

Comment: This makes only sense in the category of vector spaces. What is ["the dual of a Lie algebra"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805594/is-there-a-definition-of-a-dual-lie-algebra)? As the answer there says: *But if your question was actually "is there a natural Lie algebra structure on the vector space dual?" then I am fairly confident that the answer is no.*

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm aware that $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is just a $K$-vector space, as written above. But its elements are supposed to respect the brackets, i.e. they factor through the abelianization of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well yes the sequence in question is just a sequence of vector spaces. But I don't understand why it's clear that everything works. I mean not every functor is exact and we aren't applying the usual dual functor to vector spaces, $\mathfrak{g}^*$ in my notation is in general different from the vector space of **all** linear maps from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $K$.

Comment: Your space of all Lie algebra morphisms from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $K$ is not isomorphic to the vector space $\mathfrak{g}^*$, but rather to $(\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}])^*$, the space of isomorphism classes of all $1$-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{g}$. So we can use the Hom-functor.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, maybe I should've used a different notation, sorry for the confusion! I still don't see how considering the Hom-functor yields surjectivity of $\iota^*$, since a contravariant Hom-functor maps epimorphisms to monomorphisms but doesn't map monomorphisms to epimorphisms in general.